# Wordpress XML-RPC post success but don't work with long body

Tags: wordpress

I use code below to post via XML-RPC, it does success. But when I send a long string $bodypost, my post doesn't have body content. I test it with html code, it's working, then I remove all space, my $bodypost just have 1 line with about 4000 words, it's not working.

How can I fix it?

```
    <?php 
function send_post($titlepost, $bodypost, $categorypost, $keywordspost )  
{  
    require_once("IXR_Library.php.inc");
    $encoding='UTF-8';
    $client->debug = false; //Set it to false in Production Environment
    $title= $titlepost; // $title variable will insert your blog title 
    $body= $bodypost; // $body will insert your blog content (article content)
    $category=$categorypost; // Comma seperated pre existing categories. Ensure that these categories exists in your blog.
    $keywords=$keywordspost;
    $customfields=array('key'=>'Author-bio', 'value'=>'Autor Bio Here'); // Insert your custom values like this in Key, Value format
        $title = htmlentities($title,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);
        $keywords = htmlentities($keywords,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);
        $content = array(
            'title'=>$title,
            'description'=>$body,
            'mt_allow_comments'=>0,  // 1 to allow comments
            'mt_allow_pings'=>0,  // 1 to allow trackbacks
            'post_type'=>'post',
            'mt_keywords'=>$keywords,
            'categories'=>array($category),
            'custom_fields' =>  array($customfields)


        );

    // Create the client object
    $client = new IXR_Client('http://www.domain.com/xmlrpc.php');
     $username = "abc"; 
     $password = "abc"; 
     $params = array(0,$username,$password,$content,true); // Last parameter is 'true' which means post immideately, to save as draft set it as 'false'
    // Run a query for PHP
    if (!$client->query('metaWeblog.newPost', $params)) {
        die('Something went wrong - '.$client->getErrorCode().' : '.$client->getErrorMessage());
    }
    else
        echo "Article Posted Successfully";
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix it. This code does not work if my body code is give by source code of default Wordpress editor, but if I change it to CkEditor it's working!